# Move files to non existing directory from the command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there any single command in CMD that can move the file from one directory to a non existing one?

This is the task: Move the file SAMPLE.exe from TEST folder in to a new folder PROGRAMS located on the root level of the floppy disk.

I know how to do it with two commands but I would like to use one single command in order to achieve this.

Comment: If DOS is windows CMD, ROBOCOPY will do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `robocopy`:

```
robocopy /mov test a:\programs sample.exe
```

Comment: robocopy /mov f:\test f:\programs sample.exe 
did exactly what I wanted thank you very much.